# How can I load a sprite sheet in Flash correctly?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, sprite-sheet

As common users of flash you know that you can export images to a moveclip, doing frame per frame, but thats not very "optimized" way to do it, in C++ my friend who I can't talk with right now, have read a spritesheet and made the movements and everything by it, and since AS2 is basicly C++, that would happen to a similar code to it, but I didn't managed to find it.

The thing I want is to import same sized images from a sprite sheet like this one:
http://j.imagehost.org/0829/WoodyGX_0.jpg

They are all same sized images put together that form the sprite sheet, so there is this "algorithm" to read each one and like label it to a action use, but since I don't know that I am asking someone who could tell me the likely algorithm or a way to read that sheet, image per image into my movieclip.

Thanks for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't resist the urge to quote you:

> AS2 is basicly C++

Just because I like it.

Anyway. Yes, you  could do it, sort of, but AS2 has a rather limited toolset, so it's going to be difficult. First of all, you would need to use `BitmapData.draw()` method to create a bitmapdata object containing all pixels of the spritesheet you loaded.

Next, you can choose to either do `BitmapData.copyPixels()` or `BimtapData.draw()` (again, you can draw from another bitmapdata, using only a portion of it - you will need to look at the parameter where you are to pass a rectangle and a matrix, to tell it what part exactly to copy.

Lastly, to draw it, you would use `MovieClip.beginBitmapFill(bitmapdata)`, and draw the boundaries to fill with the bitmapdata you already have.

Comment: AS2 Movieclips don't have a graphics property. You can either use the drawing methods that belong to the MovieClip Class, or use attachBitmap.

Comment: I know this because I'm living in AS2 hell while I try to eke out enough time to rewrite in AS3 (probably just in time for ASNext)

Comment: Hmmm very good thank you i'll try that and if works i'll accept the answer, but first can you tell me how can i remove a unwanted background? by bitmap i can't right? only png or gif?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on his unpronounceableness's answer, you'll need to load your spirite sheet using a [MovieClipLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001383.html#411260). Then, you need to create a BitmapData and [draw](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00000786.html) the pixels from the MovieClip that you loaded into. You can then either use that directly as the source to draw or [copyPixels](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00000784.html#152508) to a BitmapData that is your character, calculating which piece is the pose you want each time, or you can create a number of different BitmapData instances and draw one pose to each. Then you iterate through, drawing all the pixels of one smaller bitmap onto your character each time.